# Segmentation fault error in c++ program

Tags: c++, runtime-error

There is a c++ code below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void f(const char* s)
{
    char* temp;
    strcpy(temp,s);

    cout<<temp<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    f("HELLO");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it:

```
g++ -o output main.cpp
```

It compiles without any error. But when I run it with `./output`
it gives an error  **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**
What is the problem??
PS:
OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Uninitialized local variables, like your `temp` variable, have an *indeterminate* (and in practice random) value. Using them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is a very common cause of crashes. The point here is that you need to allocate, one way or other, memory for the pointer.

Comment: You never allocate memory for `temp`:  `char* temp;`

Comment: Also, any particular reason to not be using `std::string` instead of `char*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in function f() does not allocate storage for a string.
So temp is an uninitialized pointer. The result is undefined behavior.

You tagged this as C++, so you might consider:

```
void f(const char* s)
{
   std::string temp(s);
   std::cout<<temp<<std::endl;
}
```

which works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You did not allocate any space for `temp`. It is defined as a pointer to a char type and will be initialized to some random value. When you `strcpy` your string onto the memory pointed to by that char pointer, it will try and copy the bytes from your string "HELLO" onto that memory which will almost certainly be invalid.

To correct this, ensure `temp` has some actual storage allocated. Either `char temp[buffer_size]` or use `malloc` or `new`. Or as this is C++ and not just C, use the `std::string` type from the C++ standard library.